# Div not recalculating it's width according to inner img after updating it via JS - Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6jgvdh7/1/)**

This is a weird bug in Chrome, After I update height of a div via JS it should also update it's width because it's inner child image tag height was also updated which also updated it's width & this seems to work fine in firefox but not in chrome.

I have tried many things but it seems like a paint issue with chrome. Please help!

P.S If I inspect element the image tag and disable then enable height 100% property it renders as it should !!.

**CSS**

```
.imgwrap {
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.imgwrap img{
    height: 100%;
    width: auto;
}
```

**JS**

```
$('.imgwrap').css({
    height: $(window).height()
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/L6jgvdh7/4/)**

I applied the height on image tag instead of Div and it worked!

JS:

```
$('.imgwrap img').css({
    height: $(window).height()
});
```

Comment: @geevee Thanks for the help, I solved it :) it was so simple. Check it out.

Answer (score 0):

i made a fiddle on top of yours, showing my suggestion:

http://jsfiddle.net/L6jgvdh7/2/

you should bind this logic to `$(window).resize` so it will 'stretch' when window size changes:

```
// declare resizing method
function resize_img() {
    $('.imgwrap').css({
        height: $(window).height()-50
    });
}

// bind window resize to resizing method (run on every resize)
$(window).resize(resize_img);

// resize image (once, on page load)
resize_img();
```

**BUT**, i would suggest using **pure CSS** for this case, as following:

```
<div style="background:url('path/for/background/image');background-size:cover"></div>
```

or something similar, stretching images in general should be done with CSS only for the cleanest approach.

hope that helps.

Comment: In my actual code I have it on resize function as well but it doesn't help me but it works on fiddle cuz it resizes it's window a little on first run as well.

Comment: follow the exact code in the example i made, you should (1) bind to window resize event AND (2) run the code on page load.

Comment: I was using cover images before but client wants too see complete images ... while each image having the same height.

Comment: no it's not. resize event triggers when window gets resized. period. it DOES NOT run on page load, this is why we should call `resize_img` method on page load, as well.

Comment: Actually resize function not even making any different check this out http://prntscr.com/90dnqz